# My laptop becomes extremely hot, but I don't know what to do

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, temperature, overheating

This is my laptop:

**Packard Bell Easynote TK**

*Intel Celeron Processor T3500*

I purchased it on 12 September 2010. (And it runs Windows 7).
Since already 2 years, it's getting slower. I didn't put much files on the laptop, and I didn't download a lot of programs.
But it's just slow now. When I open taskmanager, I see my processor usage is about 55%, even when I only view a single web page.
I installed Speedfan (program to see core temperatures, etc.) and I discovered that my temperatures are extremely high, I reach temps of 90 degrees.
So I googled, and read it's probably a problem with the fan. I looked into the ventilation gap at the bottom, and saw my fan spinning, but I think there is a lot of dust inside.
The dust could easily be removed if the device is screwed open, but I really don't want to do that, because I'm affraid I can't get the pieces back in their place, or I think I make the problem bigger.
I also read that cleaning it from outside with a vacuum cleaner is a bad idea too.
What can I do?

Comment: Cleaning it with a vacuum cleaner can be a bad idea since is will cause fans to spin. A fan with power input to it will spin. A fan spun by wind will generate power. Which is not something your motherboard is build for. You can prevent this by makeing sure the fan does not spin. There are also stories about static electricity and vacuumcleaners; I do not know if these are true. That only leaves you opening it, ar having soneone do it and then clean fans and possible replace dried out cooling pads.

Comment: As re getting pieces back in place: look for a service manual. Those will tell you how the laptop is disassembled and reassembled. (Not to be confused with a user manual for end users). The service manual is usually only available to technicians but some googling often provides an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Computer fans are fragile, and can be broken if you try to clean around them with a vacuum cleaner. Since you have a laptop, it is not such an easy thing to do to replace the fan, so it is worthwhile to clean the fan's heatsink carefully and thoroughly. Depending on the model it may also be difficult to open the laptop case in order to gain access to the area around the fan. When the laptop case is open, it will be possible to check if the fan is running properly. Take the laptop to a computer repair shop and have it cleaned professionally. It costs a little more than doing it yourself, but in my opinion the results will be worth it.

Comment: +1 for the computer shop. if OP is not sure about doing it her/him-self then that is a very good option.